# How do I set a custom path for feeds feed items in views?

Tags: 7, feeds, views, path-aliases

**Update**

I tried doing what Nikhil and the referenced threads said, but I'm still have trouble. I should have been more clear initially on what the problem is. When I go to `<new-feed-node-path>/feed-items` I'm given a page not found. That is, `localhost/shows/<show>/feed-items`. The URL in views for that page used to be `node/%/feed-items`, and I changed it to `shows/%/feed-items`. The paths of the feed items themselves works fine, ie. `localhost/episodes/<episode-title>` is working.

---

In pathauto settings I put:

```
Pattern for all Feed paths

shows/[node:title]

Pattern for all Feed item paths

episodes/[node:title]
```

And then in the feeds_defaults_feed_items view I put `shows/%/feed-items` in place of the default path, `node/%/feed-items`. I also tried `shows/[node:title]/feed-items`. I created a new feed each time to test.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to

Create a simple rule to delete and create url aliases after the content was saved, for the feed content type.
Used a pattern `episodes/[node:title]` which will give you the result.

Refer:

1. https://www.drupal.org/node/1161202
2. https://www.drupal.org/node/1210128

Comment: please see my update. I gave too little information initially, I think.